# Converting opencv image to gdi bitmap doesn't work depends on image size

Tags: c++, image, opencv, bitmap

I have this code that converts an opencv image to a bitmap:

```
  void processimage(MAT imageData)
  {
      Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(imageData.cols,imageData.rows,stride, PixelFormat24bppRGB,imageData.data);

   // do some work with bitmap
  }
```

It is working well when the size of image is 2748 X 3664. But I am tring to process an image wth size 1374 X 1832, it doesn't work.

The error is invalid parameter(2).

I checked and can confirm that:

in 2748 *3664:

- cols=2748
- rows=3664
- stride= 8244
- image is continues.

in 1374 X 1832

- cols=1374
- rows=1832
- stride= 4122
- image is continues.

So everything seems correct to me, but it generate error.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

## Edit

Based on answer which explained why I can not create bitmap. I finally implemented it in this way:

```
   Mat newImage;
   cvtColor(imageData, newImage, CV_BGR2BGRA);
   Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(newImage.cols,newImage.rows,newImage.step1(), PixelFormat32bppRGB,newImage.data);
```

So effectively, I convert input image to a 4 byte per pixel and then use the convert it to bitmap.

All credits to **Roger Rowland**  for his answer.

Comment: +1 that's an effective workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that a BMP format must have a stride that is a multiple of 4.

Your larger image has a stride of 8244, which is valid (8244/4 = 2061) but your smaller image has a stride of 4122, which is not (4122/4 = 1030.5).

As [it says on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the *stride* parameter (with my emphasis):

> Integer that specifies the byte offset between the beginning of one
>   scan line and the next. This is usually (but not necessarily) the
>   number of bytes in the pixel format (for example, 2 for 16 bits per
>   pixel) multiplied by the width of the bitmap. The value passed to this
>   parameter **must be a multiple of four**.

Assuming your stride is correct, I think you're only option is to copy it row by row. So, something like:

1. Great a `Gdiplus::Bitmap` of the required size and format
2. Use [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the bitmap pixel data.
3. Copy the OpenCV image one row at a time.
4. Call [UnlockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to release the bitmap data.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Thanks. That is very useful. Can you please post some code too?

Comment: @mans well, maybe later .... I'll see how I feel ... beer and Chinese food is calling right now :-)

Comment: Thanks. I found a good solution! I accepted your answer and give credit to your answer when I present what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my class CGdiPlus that implements all you need to convert from cv::Mat to Gdiplus::Bitmap and vice versa:

[OpenCV / Tesseract: How to replace libpng, libtiff etc with GDI+ Bitmap (Load into cv::Mat via GDI+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725155/opencv-tesseract-how-to-replace-libpng-libtiff-etc-with-gdi-bitmap-load-in)